# Conditions for a $(n,k,d)_q$ code to have $d>n/2$

Tags: coding-theory

This seems like such an silly question that I'm almost afraid to ask it.

Clearly some codes have $d>n/2$, for example the $(n,1,n)$ repitition code. But it doesn't seem possible to construct a binary code with $k=2$ that has $d>n/2$ (I haven't proven this, but it seems reasonable based on toying around with codebook matrices). So a reasonable conjecture would be that $d>n/2$ is possible if and only if $k<q$. Is this true?

Comment: Whatever happened to the _Singleton bound_ which says that $d \leq n-k+1$? And the notion that Reed-Solomon codes (more generally, MDS or maximal distance separable codes) satisfy the Singleton Bound with equality"

Comment: Well, give an example then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the "if and only if" part of the conjecture is quite true.  A minimum distance $d > n/2$ cannot be achieved for *all* $k < q$. A more reasonable conjecture would be that for $d$ to exceed $n/2$, it must
be that $k$ is smaller than $n/2$, but even this is not supported
by the evidence.

Consider the binary $[n,k,d] = [3,2,2]$ code with codewords
$$000\quad 011\quad 101\quad 110$$
Both $k$ and $d$ have value $2$ exceeding $n/2 = 1\frac 12$.

A doubly-extended Reed-Solomon code over a finite field with $q$ elements has parameters $[n,k,d] =[q+1,k,q+2-k]$ where the distance $d$ equals
$n-k+1$, that is, the Singleton bound is satisfied with equality.

- If $q$ is even, that is, the field has characteristic $2$, set
  $k = \frac{q+2}{2} > n/2$ to get a code with minimum distance $d = \frac{q+2}{2} > n/2$.
- If $q$ is odd, set $k=\frac{q+1}{2} = n/2$ to get a code with minimum
  distance $d = \frac{q+1}{2} + 1 > n/2$

Comment: But can we prove the "only if" part of the conjecture? It seems true but the answers do not prove it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist For a MDS code, $d = n+1-k > \frac n2$, then $k < \frac n2 +1$. Since $n$ is at most $q+1$ (though a few rare exceptions are known), it is certainly _necessary_ that $k < q$ except for the exceptional case $q=k=2$, But, the necessary condition $k < \frac n2 +1$ is stronger than $k < q$ in general and also applies to the case $q=k=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Supplementing Dilip's answer with the observation that for low dimensional codes [the Griesmer bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griesmer_bound) is more accurate than the (in the binary world mostly useless) Singleton bound. For $q=2=k$ it implies that the minimum distance of a 2-dimensional binary linear code is at most $2n/3$. When $n=3m$ is a multiple of three the bound is achieved by the linear code gotten from Dilip's example $\{(000,110,101,011)\}$ by repeating all the bits (or blocks) $m$ times. The minimum distance of the resulting code with four words is obviously $2m$.